# Get count of an array from within a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, parameter-passing, sizeof

I'm trying to write a function that prints the elements of a given array. However, I don't understand how I can count the elements of the array which is passed into my function. Here's the code:

In this example, I am trying to get the count from within my function, though this only returns 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void first_function(int ages[], char *names[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int count = sizeof(*ages) / sizeof(int);
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s has lived %d years.\n", names[i], ages[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ages[] = { 7, 32, 36 };
    char  *names[] = {
        "Tiger", "Sandy",
        "Ryan"
    };

    first_function(ages, names);
    printf("---\n");

    return 0;

}
```

In this example, I give the function an extra parameter (count), then get the count from within main. Is this the normal way to do it? It seems unclean somehow.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void first_function(int ages[], char *names[], int count) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s has lived %d years.\n", names[i], ages[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ages[] = { 7, 32, 36 };
    char  *names[] = {
        "Tiger", "Sandy",
        "Ryan"
    };

    int count = sizeof(ages) / sizeof(int);

    first_function(ages, names, count);
    printf("---\n");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: OT: Consider using  a `struct` glueing together the name and the age in *one* `struct` variable.

Comment: You can have your function provide a *meaningful* return `type` to return `count` to the calling function, and you can also use a *pointer to count* as a parameter, and make the changes to the pointer visible back in the caller. Your choice, you can do one, or both..

Comment: Your array lies in the stack frame of main function.when first_function is called. You only pass the pointer of array which is in main stack frame. So first_fun frame doesnot contain any info regarding your local frame

Comment: Any info regarding size of array..

Answer (score 5):

Your so-called unclean way is the normal way. (The `sizeof` idiom does not work if the array parameter has decayed to a pointer type). Although consider using a `size_t` type for the count, not an `int`.

Another approach is to use a particular value to signal the end of the array. Effectively this is how the string library functions work in C; with NUL signalling the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Don't why it seemed unclean as I am actually doing pretty much the same thing with the arrays.

Comment: @RyanMc: For quoted text strings (char arrays)' the compiler will always add a terminating zero (with one exception! – if you state up front how many characters are expected). For arrays of strings, I use a terminating `NULL`. The problem with a terminaing value in an integer array is that your 'magic' value may be actually valid. In your case an age of `0`... But I notice since you are using `signed int`, an 'age' of `-1` would work.

Answer (score 5):

According to the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 7 **A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted
>   to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’**, where the type qualifiers (if any)
>   are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type
>   derivation....

So this function declaration

```
void first_function(int ages[], char *names[]);
```

is equivalent to the following declaration after adjusting the corresponding parameters declared like arrays.

```
void first_function( int *ages, char **names );
```

That is the parameters `ages` and `names` have pointer types within the function.
As result this expression

```
int count = sizeof(*ages) / sizeof(int);
```

(I think you mean

```
int count = sizeof(ages) / sizeof(int);
                   ^^^^
```

nevertheless)

is equivalent to

```
int count = sizeof( int) / sizeof(int);
```

because the type of the sub-expression `*ages` is int.

If you will write the expression like

```
int count = sizeof(ages) / sizeof(int);
```

then it is equivalent to

```
int count = sizeof(int *) / sizeof(int);
```

and again will not yield the size of the array passed as the argument.

For such arrays that do not have a sentinel value you have to pass also their sizes to functions if it is required.

Thus the function should be declared like

```
void first_function(int ages[], char *names[], size_t n);
```

and called like

```
size_t count = sizeof(ages) / sizeof(*ages);

first_function(ages, names, count);
```

Pay attention to that there is no need to initialize the variable `i` within the function two times. The function can look like

```
void first_function(int ages[], char *names[], size_t count) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
        printf("%s has lived %d years.\n", names[i], ages[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can't use `sizeof` here to get the length of the array in the called function. Because *array decays into pointer* here in the called function. And that's why it will return sizeof pointer not size of array.

Solution- you need to pass another parameter specifying the size of the array or keeping a place holder like `NULL` or some value to mark the end of the array. (Well you have followed that in your second solution - which is perfectly fine and *it works*).

<sup>Return value of `sizeof` is `size_t`. Use `size_t` instead of `int`.
 It's the right way to handle what `sizeof` operator returns.</sup>